# TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined: A node js error

Tags: javascript, node.js

So I am working on a content management system in Nodejs and any time I start the server, I get this message: TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined.

The code below is in the index.js file.

```
    'use strict';

const express = require('express');
const exphnbars = require('express-handlebars');
const url =  require('url');
const { default: Storyblok } = require('storyblok-js-client');
const app = express();

//....



const storyblokClient = require('storyblok-js-client')



let storyblok = new storyblokClient({
    accessToken: 'J0irYFbngEQ6ZFlRqs6llwtt'
});

// ----
app.get('/*', function(req, res){
    var path = url.parse(req.url).pathname;
    path = path == '/'? 'home' : path;

    Storyblok
        .get(`cdn/stories/${path}`,{
            version: req.query.storyblok ? 'draft': 'published'
        })
        .then((response) => {
            res.render('index', {
                story: response.data.story
            });
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            res.send(error);
        });
});

app.use('/public', express.static('public'));

//telmplate engine
app.engine('.hbs', exphnbars({
    defaultLayout: 'main',
    extname: '.hbs',
    partialsDir: 'views/components/'
}));

app.set('view engine', '.hbs');
app.set('views', '.hbs');

app.listen(5050, function(){
    console.log('Example app listening on port 5050')
});
```

Any help, please??

Comment: `Storyblok` is undefined because you defined it in lowercase `storyblok`, fix the typo and you should be good

Answer (score 0):

You have defined `storyblok` and used `Storyblok`

The character `s` should be in lower case.

```
storyblok.get(`cdn/stories/${path}`...)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify which version do you use if your express version is 4 you need to define your router like this `const route = express.Router()`. your code works in version 3. just be sure about your version.